# How I can tracking request in Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I created a simple rest api via Flask.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
...

@app.errorhandler(404)
    def not_found(e):
        return render_template('404.html')
```

How I can tracking the request method, url, and IP address if the client access to wrong place (404 not found) in Flask. Thanks

Comment: Provide your code. Explain what your problem is and what you've done to face it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `request_method = request.method` to get request method,`request_ip_addr = request.remote_addr` to get request ip address,`request_url = request.url` to get request url;
I think you can code like this:

`@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
...
@app.errorhandler(404)
    def not_found(e):
        request_method = request.method
        request_ip_addr = request.remote_addr
        request_url = request.url
        # then you can storage this parameters to database for tracking the error request method, url, and IP address.
        return render_template('404.html')`

Comment: Thanks but the ip address not show client IP. It's always '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: I think if you visit this page, if it's not from localhost, but from external network access, remote_addr will change. I think you can try to test flask servers and browsers on different computers.

Comment: I'm running it in server with gunicorn and It still is 127.0.0.1.